# Ошибка подключения к Redis

Tags: python, redis

Раньше не работал с `redis`, решил сразу на тест взять готовый сетап от `VK Solution`, вот только не получается никак подключиться, выдает ошибку `22`, команда `ping` так же говорит что подключение не удалось. В чем может быть проблема?

```py
import redis

red_conn = redis.Redis(host='10.0.0.24', password='123password', port=6379, db=0)
red_conn.ping()
```

Ошибка:
Exception has occurred: Timeout Error
Timeout connecting to server

В том числе при выполнении этой команды

```
with redis.Redis() as red_conn:
    red_conn.keys(result)
    print(result)
```

Выходит такая ошибка:

```
Exception has occurred: ConnectionError
Error 10061 connecting to localhost:6379.
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Comment: Версия redis 5, может это влиять?

Comment: А сам то redis точно установлен и запущен? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46274033/8324991

Comment: Так и знал что я что-то упустил, спасибо.

Comment: Все теперь работает

Comment: Почему то библиотека redis спокойно работает на внутреннем постоянном ip, а вот библиотека aioredis не хочет, она работает только на внешнем плавающем ip (который VK предоставляет возможность отдельно выпустить), а при обращении на внутренний ip вызывает ошибку подключения 22, почему так? В целом меня все устраивает, но просто интересно, кто нибудь знает ответ?

Comment: Добавьте это всё в сам вопрос и вообще перепишите его с учётом новой информации, тогда больше вероятность, что кто-то ответит